# How to handle input type=file in Jquery while uploading file?

Tags: jquery

I searched a lot. Every time anyone asked about file uploading by jquery, as answers he got only some links of **jquery plugin**. Can anyone tell me why plugin is needed? **why simple ajax is not working in this context?**

*Tuition is preferable than solution.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only upload files by posting the form that contains the file input. You can't upload files using AJAX.

The reason for this is security. A user can select a file to be uploaded, but the only thing that the Javascript code can do is to upload the file using a post, it can't access the file data or upload it any other way.

Comment: With plugins like uploadify it is possible. or isn't it ajax?

Comment: @genesis: It uses a flash component. A component can access file data, but with just Javascript/jQuery it's not possible.

Comment: @Guffa - so where is the security when some one can upload files using flash component through JS?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[type='file']").hide();
```

will hide input with file type.

Comment: @Abhishek: So you need plugin... no way

Comment: @Abhishek: because type isn't simple text, but binary data.

Comment: So whats there in those plugins? There is no way to handle binary data in ajax(jquery)?

Comment: @Abhishek: these plugins are shockwave/flash and they use another method

Comment: @Abhishek: The problem is not that it's binary data, the problem is that the Javascript code can't access the data.

Comment: @guffa - SO with the help of JS(no shockwave/flash) we cant upload files? :(

Comment: @genesis - Yess. I saw there they have used some flash/shockwave